# Unclear equation in my scriptum (perhaps cauchy-product)

Tags: analysis, cauchy-product

[image: here is the image]

Hi the following equation in my scriptum seems unclear. I think it has something to do with cauchy-product but i dont know

Comment: i would guess you can derive it by differentiating a power series expansion of some known function.

Comment: @HansLundmark. Not exactly the same Q but close enough, to within a multiplication by $x$.